# how to remove route displayed on google map in android?

Tags: java, android, routes, android-maps

I have multiple markers on my map view and when I click on marker it show route from current location to marker.

but when I click on next marker it shows the route but not remove first route.
how can I remove first route when new route is draw on map

the code using by me is

in on click listener on marker I call DrawPath method like this:

```
    GeoPoint srcpoint = new GeoPoint(Source geopoint);

    GeoPoint destpoint = new GeoPoint(Destination geo point);

    DrawPath(srcpoint, destpoint, Color.GRAY, mapView);
```

and the DrawPath method is:

```
  private void DrawPath(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest, int color,
          MapView mMapView01) {



        // connect to map web service
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
        urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
        Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());

        //System.out.println(urlString);
        // get the kml (XML) doc. And parse it to get the coordinates(direction route).
        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
          url = new URL(urlString.toString());
          urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
          urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
          urlConnection.connect();

          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

          if(doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength()>0)
          {
            //String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName();
            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue() ;
            Log.d("xxx","path="+ path);
            String [] pairs = path.split(" ");
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude lngLat[1]=latitude lngLat[2]=height
            // src
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
            //mMapView01.getOverlays().add(overlayitem);
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;
            for(int i=1;i<pairs.length;i++) // the last one would be crash
            {
              lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
              gp1 = gp2;
              // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
              gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
              mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MapRouteOverlay(gp1,gp2,2,color));
              Log.d("xxx","pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
            //mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MapRouteOverlay(dest,dest, 3)); // use the default color
          }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


      }
```

and the class MapRouteOverlay.java used in above method is:

```
      public class MapRouteOverlay extends Overlay {

     private GeoPoint gp1;
   private GeoPoint gp2;

   private int mode=0;
   private int defaultColor;




   public MapRouteOverlay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode) // GeoPoint is a int. (6E)
    {
      this.gp1 = gp1;
      this.gp2 = gp2;
      this.mode = mode;
     defaultColor = 999; // no defaultColor

  }

  public MapRouteOverlay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode, int defaultColor)
  {
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
  }

  public int getMode()
  {
    return mode;
  }

  public boolean draw
     (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
    {
       Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

  if (shadow == false)
  {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Point point = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(gp1, point);

    if(mode==2)
    {
      if(defaultColor==999)
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      else
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      Point point2 = new Point();
      projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
      paint.setAlpha(120);
    //  canvas.restore();
      canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
    }

  }
  return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}
}
```

How to remove first path when new path is drawn by code?

Comment: +1 I hav the same problem . Do you solve it? Kindly suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to keep all those overlays that you are making in for loop (MapRouteOverlay) in some kind of list, then when you click on next overlay, you will have to remove all those from map............

Answer (score 0):

as I see in your code you add your route to the map with

```
mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MapRouteOverlay(gp1,gp2,2,color));
```

but you dont remove the old route 
with `new` keyword you put every time a new route into the map overlay
make a member variable with your route and then remove them each time before you add a new route